# How do I create a WPF Rounded Corner container?

Tags: wpf, rounded-corners

We are creating an XBAP application that we need to have rounded corners in various locations in a single page and we would like to have a WPF Rounded Corner container to place a bunch of other elements within.  Does anyone have some suggestions or sample code on how we can best accomplish this?   Either with styles on a  or with creating a custom control?

Comment: Caveat: if you put a single line of text inside a rounded-rectangle border, old people like me will look at it and think, "Macintosh '80s push button!"

Comment: You have no idea how badly I miss the 80's Macintosh!  I think this question should explicitly state whether or not clipping the corners is desired because the selected answer doesn't clip the border.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

You don't need a custom control, just put your container in a border element:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8">
   <Grid/>
</Border>
```

You can replace the `<Grid/>` with any of the layout containers...

Comment: For any thickness object (BorderThickness or CornerRadius) you can specify a single number if all 4 are the same, such as CornerRadius="8".

Comment: `<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8">` is a suitable replacement for this, a bit more succint

Comment: @Patrik Deoghare, don't me wrong, kobusb is awesome ... but I think the WPF team was freaking awesome for building this in and making it so easy to take advantage of. (Although one could argue that a modern UI platform that doesn't have this built in ... really isn't a modern UI platform.)

Comment: By the way, the implementation of Border is extremely enlightening ... if you feel like digging under the covers. For example, how it uses StreamGeometry ...

Comment: It does not work for me. To get round corners on a Canvas I must use a BorderThickness as large as the CornerRadius.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either and I am using .NET 4.5 and a StackPanel

Comment: OK, I got it to work by increasing the border thickness, but this solution doesn't clip the corners of the children within the container.  It only prevents the corners from overlapping the border radius by restraining the heights and widths of the children.  Chris Cavanagh's solution handles this case.  Sadly, I was hoping this solution worked because it seems more efficient and elegant.

Answer (score 61):

I know that this isn't an answer to the initial question ... but you often want to clip the inner content of that rounded corner border you just created.

Chris Cavanagh has come up with an [excellent way](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/wpf-easy-rounded-corners-for-anything/) to do just this.

I have tried a couple different approaches to this ... and I think this one rocks.

Here is the xaml below:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Background="Black"
>
    <!-- Rounded yellow border -->
    <Border
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        BorderBrush="Yellow"
        BorderThickness="3"
        CornerRadius="10"
        Padding="2"
    >
        <Grid>
            <!-- Rounded mask (stretches to fill Grid) -->
            <Border
                Name="mask"
                Background="White"
                CornerRadius="7"
            />

            <!-- Main content container -->
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Use a VisualBrush of 'mask' as the opacity mask -->
                <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=mask}"/>
                </StackPanel.OpacityMask>

                <!-- Any content -->
                <Image Source="http://chriscavanagh.files.wordpress.com/2006/12/chriss-blog-banner.jpg"/>
                <Rectangle
                    Height="50"
                    Fill="Red"/>
                <Rectangle
                    Height="50"
                    Fill="White"/>
                <Rectangle
                    Height="50"
                    Fill="Blue"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Page>
```

Comment: The Blacklight Controls (http://blacklight.codeplex.com/) also have a nifty little control called ClippingBorder that also allows you to clip the content to your rounded corners. One nice thing about ClippingBorder is that it doesn't use a VisualBrush (which is one of the highest cost (in terms of performance) brushes).

Comment: However, I just took a look inside the implementation of the ClippingBorder ... and it uses 4 ContentControl(s) in its default ControlTemplate (one for each of the corners) ... so I am not sure if it is more or less performant than the VisualBrush approach above. I would speculate maybe less performant.

Comment: This should be the answer chosen if clipping is required.

Comment: This is the only real way of doing this ! 
It's amazing this isn't the default behavior for elements inside a border .

Comment: @eranotzap Glad you liked this answer. The only downside is that you are using a VisualBrush which is a more performance heavy item. My other answer below shows you how to avoid this VisualBrush ...

Answer (score 20):

I just had to do this myself, so I thought I would post another answer here.

Here is another way to create a rounded corner border *and clip its inner content*. This is the straightforward way by using the Clip property. It's nice if you want to avoid a VisualBrush.

The xaml:

```
<Border
    Width="200"
    Height="25"
    CornerRadius="11"
    Background="#FF919194"
>
    <Border.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry
            RadiusX="{Binding CornerRadius.TopLeft, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}"
            RadiusY="{Binding RadiusX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        >
            <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                <MultiBinding
                    Converter="{StaticResource widthAndHeightToRectConverter}"
                >
                    <Binding
                        Path="ActualWidth"
                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}"
                    />
                    <Binding
                        Path="ActualHeight"
                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}"
                    />
                </MultiBinding>
            </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
        </RectangleGeometry>
    </Border.Clip>

    <Rectangle
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        Fill="Blue"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
    />
</Border>
```

The code for the converter:

```
public class WidthAndHeightToRectConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double width = (double)values[0];
        double height = (double)values[1];
        return new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cool solution.  I'm creating a control template for a button that needs both an outer glow and an inner glow in different states, and this helped to solve the problem.

Comment: Signed in just to give you an upvote after struggling with OpacityMask issues for hours.

Answer (score 2):

VB.Net code based implementation of kobusb's Border control solution. I used it to populate a ListBox of Button controls. The Button controls are created from MEF extensions. Each extension uses MEF's ExportMetaData attribute for a Description of the extension. The extensions are VisiFire charting objects. The user pushes a button, selected from the list of buttons, to execute the desired chart.

```vb
        ' Create a ListBox of Buttons, one button for each MEF charting component. 
    For Each c As Lazy(Of ICharts, IDictionary(Of String, Object)) In ext.ChartDescriptions
        Dim brdr As New Border
        brdr.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black
        brdr.BorderThickness = New Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2)
        brdr.CornerRadius = New CornerRadius(8, 8, 8, 8)
        Dim btn As New Button
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf GenericButtonClick
        brdr.Child = btn
        brdr.Background = btn.Background
        btn.Margin = brdr.BorderThickness
        btn.Width = ChartsLBx.ActualWidth - 22
        btn.BorderThickness = New Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)
        btn.Height = 22
        btn.Content = c.Metadata("Description")
        btn.Tag = c
        btn.ToolTip = "Push button to see " & c.Metadata("Description").ToString & " chart"
        Dim lbi As New ListBoxItem
        lbi.Content = brdr
        ChartsLBx.Items.Add(lbi)
    Next

Public Event Click As RoutedEventHandler

Private Sub GenericButtonClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim c As Lazy(Of ICharts, IDictionary(Of String, Object)) = DirectCast(btn.Tag, Lazy(Of ICharts, IDictionary(Of String, Object)))
    Dim w As Window = DirectCast(c.Value, Window)
    Dim cc As ICharts = DirectCast(c.Value, ICharts)
    c.Value.CreateChart()
    w.Show()
End Sub

<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Export(GetType(ICharts))> _
<System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportMetadata("Description", "Data vs. Time")> _
Public Class DataTimeChart
    Implements ICharts

    Public Sub CreateChart() Implements ICharts.CreateChart
    End Sub
End Class

Public Interface ICharts
    Sub CreateChart()
End Interface

Public Class Extensibility
    Public Sub New()
        Dim catalog As New AggregateCatalog()

        catalog.Catalogs.Add(New AssemblyCatalog(GetType(Extensibility).Assembly))

        'Create the CompositionContainer with the parts in the catalog
        ChartContainer = New CompositionContainer(catalog)

        Try
            ChartContainer.ComposeParts(Me)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' must use Lazy otherwise instantiation of Window will hold open app. Otherwise must specify Shutdown Mode of "Shutdown on Main Window".
    <ImportMany()> _
    Public Property ChartDescriptions As IEnumerable(Of Lazy(Of ICharts, IDictionary(Of String, Object)))

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to put a button in a rounded-rectangle border, you should check out [msdn's example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613545.aspx). I found this by googling for images of the problem (instead of text). Their bulky outer rectangle is (thankfully) easy to remove.

Note that you will have to redefine the button's behavior (since you've changed the ControlTemplate). That is, you will need to define the button's behavior when clicked using a Trigger tag (Property="IsPressed" Value="true") in the ControlTemplate.Triggers tag. Hope this saves someone else the time I lost :)