# how to create a rect button in xaml

Tags: xaml

hai guys
i need your help to create a rectangle button with xaml.

if we create a default button will rounded rectangle button.
and i not found corner radius setting..
please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own Style for your button.
Take a loot at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28VS.95%29.aspx) example, and then you can play with RadiusX RadiusY properties of both Rectangles to avoid rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic style would be:

```
<Rectangle>
    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Rectangle>
```

That would be a very basic button style that has rect corners. I still suggest to read blurg's link for more info, as this can be very flexible and/or complex ;)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MSDN example for creating fancy buttons [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613545.aspx). Also take a look at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120851/how-do-i-create-a-wpf-rounded-corner-container) question.